# Android connect to CC2540 keyfob BLE using keyfobdemo app

Tags: android

I have CC2540 keyfob BLE device and I want to connect to this device using Android app. Device offers different services and characteristics, those has UUID for each. So I want all these UUID. I am unable to find it on TI site (http://www.ti.com/) or I am missing something.Anyone can help me to find out UUIDs for keyfobdemo app which contains Proximity Profile with services and characteristics like 
Link Loss Service, Immediate Alert Service, TX Power Level Service, Battery Service, Accelerometer Service, Simple Keys Service.

Comment: i am facing the same problem  did you find the solution..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you need to go through the Keyfob source code project in IAR Embedded Workbench IDE. Go to the Project directory and look for a folder called PROFILES, there is a file called gatt_profile_uuid.h

you can find most of the Keyfob service and characteristic UUID there. some other service like simple Key service UUID is defined in their respective Profile header.

```
* GATT Service UUIDs
#define IMMEDIATE_ALERT_SERV_UUID       0x1802  // Immediate Alert
#define LINK_LOSS_SERV_UUID             0x1803  // Link Loss
#define TX_PWR_LEVEL_SERV_UUID          0x1804  // Tx Power
#define CURRENT_TIME_SERV_UUID          0x1805  // Current Time Service
#define REF_TIME_UPDATE_SERV_UUID       0x1806  // Reference Time Update Service
#define NEXT_DST_CHANGE_SERV_UUID       0x1807  // Next DST Change Service
#define GLUCOSE_SERV_UUID               0x1808  // Glucose
#define THERMOMETER_SERV_UUID           0x1809  // Health Thermometer
#define DEVINFO_SERV_UUID               0x180A  // Device Information
#define NWA_SERV_UUID                   0x180B  // Network Availability
#define HEARTRATE_SERV_UUID             0x180D  // Heart Rate
#define PHONE_ALERT_STS_SERV_UUID       0x180E  // Phone Alert Status Service
#define BATT_SERV_UUID                  0x180F  // Battery Service
#define BLOODPRESSURE_SERV_UUID         0x1810  // Blood Pressure
#define ALERT_NOTIF_SERV_UUID           0x1811  // Alert Notification Service
#define HID_SERV_UUID                   0x1812  // Human Interface Device
#define SCAN_PARAM_SERV_UUID            0x1813  // Scan Parameters
#define RSC_SERV_UUID                   0x1814  // Running Speed and Cadence
#define CSC_SERV_UUID                   0x1816  // Cycling Speed and Cadence
#define CYCPWR_SERV_UUID                0x1818  // Cycling Power
#define LOC_NAV_SERV_UUID               0x1819  // Location and Navigation
```

The above is something you could find in that header file. Therefore, the TI official iOS app can retrieved your service based on these uuid definition.

I hope this can be helpful for you.

Comment: can u provide me some characteristic list ...? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you only want to know all UUIDs themselves in keyfob?
like:

> // Proximity Profile Service UUIDs
>
> ## define LINK_LOSS_SERVICE_UUID          0x1500
>
> This UUID may be changed in CC2541 codes coz my source is for CC2540.(old)

Or want to know how to modify UUIDs in keyfob to meet with android side?
in that case, do you have source codes for Keyfob and 8051 complier? (see  CC254x user's guide first)

Anyway, source codes, docs and guide are here:
http://www.ti.com/tool/cc2541dk-mini